# Install older versions of google-chrome-stable, on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, chrome

I am able to do,

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

This installs, chrome version 45 which does not support NPAPI plug-ins that is needed to run java inside browser.

I am trying to move one or two versions older, so that i can use this feature, but there is no info on net available.

In the meanwhile,

```
sudo dpkg-query -l "*google-chrome*"
```

shows only chrome 45.

```
ii  google-chrome-stable           45.0.2454.101-1      amd64                The web browser from Google
```

Does it mean, chrome doesn't allow people to use older versions?

Note: people suggesting me to use firefox for java plugin will get -ve points

Comment: I found some older versions of chromium here:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/?C=M;O=D

Answer (score 60):

I know this question is a bit old, but in case you came here willing to do this from the terminal, you can use this command:

```
wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}-1_amd64.deb \
  && apt install -y /tmp/chrome.deb \
  && rm /tmp/chrome.deb
```

You'll need to replace `${CHROME_VERSION}` with the specific version you want, which can be found [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable).

For those wanting to do it in a Dockerfile, you can use this:

```
# Check available versions here: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable
ARG CHROME_VERSION="81.0.4044.113-1"
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}-1_amd64.deb \
  && apt install -y /tmp/chrome.deb \
  && rm /tmp/chrome.deb
```

Comment: that links works with the version you provided but I can't get it working with version 78, tried 78.0.3904.87, 78.0.3904.70 etc. any ideas will very helpful thanks

Comment: You forgot the "-1" at the end. I just tried this URL and it works: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_78.0.3904.87-1_amd64.deb
You can find the complete identifiers in the link I put in my answer, just navigate over the pages until you find the version you are looking for.

Comment: you are absolutely right, adding "-1" fixed the URL. Thanks you very much for your help

Comment: weird, getting a 404 for 73.0.3683.75-1 . Triple checked the version name but still not found http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_73.0.3683.75-1_amd64.deb:Tried a few other ones and same thing. Pretty unfortunate, was looking forward to installing it in docker

Comment: Change the google links to `https` - plain http will fail

Comment: +1 for adding the `-1` fixing the 404 issue.

Comment: Getting 404.  Has the URL changed?

Comment: @JoseMartinez make sure you add -1 to the end of the version.

Comment: List of version available: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable

Comment: +100 for adding -1 at the end, fixing 404 error

Comment: solution still working in 2023, thx

Comment: Check this link with versions of google chrome stable https://chromium.cypress.io/

Comment: I needed to remove the package lock first: `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` also, I needed to add `--allow-downgrades` to make it `apt install -y --allow-downgrades /tmp/chrome.deb` (and I used `sudo` on that but not sure if I needed to!)

Answer (score 13):

See: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/google-chrome-stable

There you can found older versions. Just download the .deb you need and install it.

Comment: no  63.0.3239.84

Answer (score 9):

The **only way** I found to install older version of chrome for Linux (Ubuntu), was to find the full version from here:

1. https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable?id=202706&page=1 ,
2. copy it and construct the exact URL for Google to find it -
   http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_<FULL_CHROME_BROWSER_VERSION>_amd64.deb

> For example, we want to install Major Version: 85.0

In order to be able to install it, we need some standalone installer that is available in dl.google.com. The problem is that directories are forbidden and the exact URL of the file should be provided. To construct the full URL to the download file, we need to find the full version from here https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable?id=202706&page=1 .
If take **Version: 85.0.4183.102-1**, our standalone installer URL will be -> http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_85.0.4183.102-1_amd64.deb

There's also such question in google support -> https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/33913561?hl=en (not answered yet)

Comment: Could you complete your “For example:”?

Comment: Looks like this is no longer available. I tried with this and it didn't work: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_73.0.3683.75-1_amd64.deb

Comment: @RobertSinclair I guess the version is too old and it's not available. I've tried with **75.0.3770.80-1** and it worked -> [link] (https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_75.0.3770.80-1_amd64.deb)

Comment: @vickypenkova yep you're right, thank you!

Comment: This works also for centos, but with a diferent URL format. I used the following URL to get version 90, which I htink is the latest verison that works with CentOS 7: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/google-chrome-stable-90.0.4430.212-1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: is it possible to get the full version name(e.g. 107.0.5304.110) if major version is given (e.g.107) through script to construct the url ? I was trying to list all versions for package "google-chrome-stable" and then grep through output as major version known but not successful yet. @vickypenkova

Answer (score 3):

You can't, unfortunately. Google removes all but the latest version from the PPA and from their download site.

You'll need to build your own repo of deb files to use when installing older versions.

Answer (score 2):

Specific chrome browser versions are not possible using the official dl.google.com repository. Google removed old versions from the repository which leads to just have one available version (the stable), it can be also a APT issue.

This is sad because developers use specific browser drivers compatible with required chrome version. In my case the CI always fails once in a weak because google removes specific versions from the repository... really really sad T.T

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to:
   **https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable**
2. There you will find a list of current and previous Google chrome versions, for example:

   - Version: 110.0.5481.77-1  2023-02-07 20:08:57 UTC
   - Version: 109.0.5414.119-1 2023-01-24 20:10:02 UTC
   - Version: 109.0.5414.74-1  2023-01-10 20:08:20 UTC
3. Grab the version number you want
4. Visit the site https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_xxx_amd64.deb replacing "xxx" section with the exact version number you've obtained in step 1. For example if we want Google Chrome version `109.0.5414.119-1` the url would look like this: https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_109.0.5414.119-1_amd64.deb
5. Once the download is complete, open a terminal window and navigate to the directory where the deb file is located.
6. Install the deb file by running the following command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i <deb_file_name>.deb
   ```
7. If you encounter any dependencies issues during the installation, run the following command to resolve them:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
8. Once the installation is complete, you can launch Chrome from the terminal using the following command:

   ```
   google-chrome-stable
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 97 as Debian package for amd64 is available under https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_97.0.4692.71-1_amd64.deb

Answer (score -2):

Follow below steps and specify old the stable version you want to install.

**1. Download Google’s signing key and add it to keyring to verify integrity of package**
 wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

**2. Set the repository**
(For 64-bit system)
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

(For 32-bit System)
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

**3. Update package list**
  apt-get update

**4. Install the stable version of Google Chrome**
  apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable=**specify-chrome-stable-version** -- 
  no-install-recommends

Comment: this does not work since, there's only one version always, the current one. No way to get older ones.

Comment: can't downvote you, can you read the OP before posting?